# Why response of firebase realtime database not reflect to html in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display response of firebase realtime database to HTML page with AngularJS as follow `{{ pps }}`.

**Controller.js**

```
firebase.database().ref('/activeUsers/9791009080').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    $scope.pps = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().msisdn) || 'Anonymous';
    console.log($scope.pps);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<h1>{{ pps }}</h1>
```

Problem is frontend HTML value is not reflected when I've found value inside `console.log` Please let me know what I've missed above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$scope.$apply` to tell angular about the changes.

```
firebase.database().ref('/activeUsers/9791009080').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  $scope.$apply(() => {
    $scope.pps = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().msisdn) || 'Anonymous';
    console.log($scope.pps);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your new to using Angular 1 + Firebase, I would recommend you to try out AngularFire. It does a better integration than your vanilla angular approach.

Check it out here.

https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md

Peace.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below solution.

```
firebase.database().ref('/activeUsers/9791009080').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.pps = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().msisdn) || 'Anonymous';
    });
});
```

**Now, why this?**
Actually, the event will occur `$apply` scope as out scope so need to tell angular that there is some event to handle. You can do this via `$timeout` or you can try `$apply` scope.

Here, I'm using `$timeout` because this will doesn't throw an error even though it will maintain the flow while event from firebase occured.